# Is the Centroid and Circumcenter of a triangle affine invariant?

Tags: affine-geometry, centroid

As the title says, are the centroid and circumcenter of a triangle affine invariant? And how would I go about proving it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean invariant (unchanged by an affine transformation), or do you mean that it transforms by the affine transformation acting on the triangle?

Comment: Affinities preserve midpoints, hence medians and the centroid. The circumcenter is not affine invariant and it is not difficult to prove it by mapping a right triangle into an acute-angled triangle, for instance. The circumcenter moves from the boundary to the interior, in such a case.

Comment: Affine transformations do not, in general, preserve right angles. The circumcenter of a triangle  lies on one of its sides iff  it is a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Note that centroid is invariant since it is the intersection of medians, which intersect with a fixed ratio (2:1), whereas the cirumcenter can't be in general (think to a right triangle transformed in a equilateral triangle).